# HBase TimeoutIOException

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hbase

I am trying to fetch the HBase data using spark and scala. However, I am getting an error which I am not able to contemplate.

Code

```
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HConstants
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.{HBaseAdmin, Result}
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.ImmutableBytesWritable
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableInputFormat
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
object HBase {
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
val tableName = "posts"
val sc = new SparkContext(new SparkConf().setAppName("HBaseReadWrite").setMaster("local[4]"))
val conf = HBaseConfiguration.create()
conf.set(HConstants.ZOOKEEPER_QUORUM, "localhost")
conf.set(TableInputFormat.INPUT_TABLE, tableName)

val admin = new HBaseAdmin(conf)
if(!admin.isTableAvailable(conf.get(tableName))) {
  println("Table doesn't exist")
  return
}
val hBaseRDD = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(conf, classOf[TableInputFormat],
  classOf[ImmutableBytesWritable], classOf[Result])
println(hBaseRDD.map(x => x._2).map(result => Bytes.toString(result.getRow)).collect().take(5).mkString("\n"))

}
}
```

build.sbt

```
name := "NLPAnnotationController"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.5"

resolvers += "Cloudera Repository" at "https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos/"
resolvers += "sonatype snapshots" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"

organization := "com.scryAnalytics"

val hadoop_version = "0.98.19-hadoop2"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.10" % "1.2.0",
  "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-spark" % "1.2.0-cdh5.7.2",
  "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-client" % hadoop_version excludeAll(ExclusionRule(organization = "javax.servlet", name="javax.servlet-api"), ExclusionRule(organization = "org.mortbay.jetty", name="jetty"), ExclusionRule(organization = "org.mortbay.jetty", name="servlet-api-2.5")),
  "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-common" % hadoop_version excludeAll(ExclusionRule(organization = "javax.servlet", name="javax.servlet-api"), ExclusionRule(organization = "org.mortbay.jetty", name="jetty"), ExclusionRule(organization = "org.mortbay.jetty", name="servlet-api-2.5")),
  "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-server" % hadoop_version excludeAll(ExclusionRule(organization = "javax.servlet", name="javax.servlet-api"), ExclusionRule(organization = "org.mortbay.jetty", name="jetty"), ExclusionRule(organization = "org.mortbay.jetty", name="servlet-api-2.5")),
  "org.scala-lang" % "scala-library" % "2.10.5",
  "it.nerdammer.bigdata" % "spark-hbase-connector_2.10" % "1.0.3"
)
```

Error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hbase/exceptions/TimeoutIOException
at HBase$.main(HBase.scala:20)
at HBase.main(HBase.scala)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.exceptions.TimeoutIOException
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
```

I have tried changing the versions of the dependencies, still no progress. 
Any help would be great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would guess that you are using a distributed system, and your local program is communicating with a remote system (database, or Hadoop). Hadoop throws an exception, which is returned to you serialized, via a network protocol. On your end, the app wants to deserialize an error message into an exception object of type `org/apache/hadoop/hbase/exceptions/TimeoutIOException`. For this, it needs to find that class in the classpath, but fails. Do you have that library in your local classpath? If not, add it

Comment: which libraries are you talking about? I have hbase dependencies in build file.

Comment: @wadhwasahil: you can set timeout using `conf.setInt("timeout", 120000)` also you need to check you have all the dependencies are available when you run your job, you can pass Hbase dependencies using --jars if you use spark-submit command.

Comment: I am running my code on intellij. Aren't all the dependencies met through sbt file?

Comment: I do not believe that your dependencies are being met, and you may have fallen into Dependency hell. Please check your spark version, in relation to Hbase, and then your dependency with Hbase Spark.

Comment: My HBase version is  0.98.19-hadoop2 and scala version is 1.6.1.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably, the jar file you provide to workers doesn't contain classes from your dependencies. Build "fat" jar using [sbt-assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly) and upload it to spark.